# Changing the compiler executable in a custom MSBuild toolset

Tags: msbuild, vs-extensibility

I'm writing a VS integration for a custom C++ toolchain (.props, .targets, .xml files).  Where can I specify the path to the compiler executable?  If I set the value of `<ExecutablePath>` then it will search for `cl.exe` in that folder, but what if my program is not called `cl.exe`?  Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835043/how-to-override-compile-command-of-visual-studio-2017-community and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761708/msbuild-set-path-to-cl ?

Comment: Thanks, that looks very promising.  I'll give it a try!