# What is the official way to access the Visual Studio 2019 version of clang from the command prompt?

Tags: clang, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to access the Visual Studio 2019 version of clang from the command prompt. I am looking for the **official** way to do this. So far it doesn't appear to be documented in any of [the MSVC/clang blog posts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/category/clang/). (Please note that I am *not* looking for other ways to build/install clang on Windows. This question specifically relates to the VS2019 clang component.)

Using the Visual Studio Installer, I have installed Visual Studio 2019 Professional (version 16.4.1) along with the optional "C++ Clang tools for Windows (9.0.0 - x64/x86)". The clang toolchain appears to be installed at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin`

(Perhaps I could add this directory to PATH, but this is not robust. Nor could I find this approach documented in any of Microsoft's docs.)

My final goal is to use `clang-cl` with scons. But as a first step, I would like to be able to run `clang-cl` from the command prompt.

When I run `vcvarsall.bat` none of the clang tools are available at the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Ross>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.4.1
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

C:\Users\Ross>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28314 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

C:\Users\Ross>clang
'clang' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Ross>clang++
'clang++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Ross>clangcl
'clangcl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Ross>clang-cl
'clang-cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**UPDATE 26 February, 2020:** Still no satisfactory answer from Microsoft. You can view Microsoft's non-answer and also vote for this issue at: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/875419/how-to-use-msvc-installed-c-clang-tools-for-window.html

Comment: This related question deals with using `clang-cl` with MSBuild but not on the command line: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30761708/2013747

Comment: This related question deals with using an earlier version of `clang-cl` with CMake and Ninja, but doesn't describe how to get `clang-cl` into the PATH https://stackoverflow.com/q/47581784/2013747

Comment: This related question deals with setting up an LLVM build of `clang` to use headers from an earlier version Visual Studio https://stackoverflow.com/q/18711595/2013747

Comment: I have this same problem.

Comment: Microsoft's forum is no help: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/875419/how-to-use-msvc-installed-c-clang-tools-for-window.html?inRegister=true

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal.

Accordingly to this post on [visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-use-msvc-installed-c-clang-tools-for-window/875419), they forgot to add the path to either some *env variable* or the `path` itself.

But, don't be afraid, there's a simple and correct way using `vswhere`.

```
function Get-VsWhere {
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "1")][String] $component,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "1")][String] $find,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "2")][String] $property
    )
    if (-not (Get-Command ./.build/vswhere.exe -ea Ignore)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory ./.build/ -Force | Out-Null
        Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/releases/download/3.1.7/vswhere.exe -OutFile ./.build/vswhere.exe
    }
    $vswhere = (Get-Item ./.build/vswhere.exe).FullName
    if ($find) {
        & $vswhere -latest -requires $component -find $find
    }
    elseif ($property) {
        & $vswhere -latest -property $property
    }
}


function Get-Clang {
    if (-not $script:_clang) {
        $script:_clang = Get-VsWhere `
            -component Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Llvm.Clang `
            -find '**/x64/**/clang.exe'
    }
    $script:_clang
}

$clang = Get-Clang
Add-PathVariable (Split-Path -Parent $clang)

# Add-PathVariable is from PSCX, it does what's on the label
```