# Unexpected compiler version, expected clang 8.0 or newer

Tags: visual-studio, clang, visual-studio-2019

I had used `__clang__` to make use of clang compiler for my project in my visual studio 2019 but now it gives strange error like

```
Error   C1189   #error:  STL1000: Unexpected compiler version, expected Clang 8.0.1 or newer. MediaServer   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\yvals_core.h    417
```

where as my clang version 9.0

```
C:\Users\geeker>clang --version
clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: i686-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin
```

Can anyone suggest any workarounds.

**EDIT** : There is a hack which actually solves the issue. That is just defining _ALLOW_COMPILER_AND_STL_VERSION_MISMATCH. But it introduces thousands of error's 
 from MSVC.

Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316239/what-is-the-official-way-to-access-the-visual-studio-2019-version-of-clang-from

Comment: my commands of clang is been identified, as posted in my question.

Comment: Just saying that it seems inherently broken per data in the linked question. Maybe there are different failures, depending on VS2019 version

Comment: Is there a way to make visual studio use clang without adding __clang__ in the processor definitions.